# Azure Media Player not playing video in Angular JS on revisit the view

Tags: angularjs, azure-media-services

I have consumed the azure media player in my angularjs application and able to view the video. But on revisit the same view where the video tag present, not playing the video, but audio is playing in the background.

I am using ui-router for routing.

Thanks in advance for a quick help.

Here is my angular js code to view the video

```
    var myOptions = {
"nativeControlsForTouch": false,
controls: true,
autoplay: false,
width: "640",
height: "400",
}
var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
myPlayer.src([
    {
            "src": 
  "//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-
   faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest",
            "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"

    }
]);
amp("azuremediaplayer").ready(function(){
 var myPlayer = this;


 myPlayer.play();
});

 **HTML tag**
 <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-
   big-play-centered" tabindex="0"></video>
```

Comment: May be you want to put your `angularJS` code??

Answer (score 3):

I also face the same issue while using azure media player.
After dispose the player on closing window will get resolved this issue.

```
myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", {
                        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                        controls: true,
                        autoplay: true
                    })
myPlayer.dispose();
```